# Redirect page based on user role in identity in .Net 5

Tags: asp.net-identity, .net-5

I wrote the project with net 5. and used identity tables for login... Now the question is that I have two dashboard forms that I want to be able to see that page based on which role the user logs in with.. I have two user roles, sales and trade.

```
  public IActionResult Index()
    {
        if (ClaimTypes.Role.Contains("Sales"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "TradeDashboard");
        }
    }
```

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: I asked my question, the code I wrote does not work, and regardless of the role, only the else part is read
If I have defined roles and relationships with roles in the relevant tables

Comment: The `ClaimTypes`  class does not do what you think it does: [it's just a `static` set of  excessively verbose SOAP claim type names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimtypes?view=net-6.0) - you need to inspect the current `ClaimsIdentity` or `ClaimsPrincipal` and get the `Role` claim(s) from that.

Comment: I'm new to programming, can you give me some advice on how to write?